# Filling dataset with dataadapter with row limit

Tags: c#, .net, database, dataset, dataadapter

I need to modify the following code so that the number of rows are limited.

```
// create the connection
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=oracledb;
    User Id=UserID;Password=Password;");

// create the command for the stored procedure
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT_JOB_HISTORY.GetJobHistoryByEmployeeId";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// add the parameters for the stored procedure including the REF CURSOR
// to retrieve the result set
cmd.Parameters.Add("p_employee_id", OracleType.Number).Value = 101;
cmd.Parameters.Add("cur_JobHistory", OracleType.Cursor).Direction =
    ParameterDirection.Output;

// createt the DataAdapter from the command and use it to fill the
// DataSet
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);//Here is where I need to limit the rows
```

I know there is fill method which takes a maximum count.

[public int Fill(
    DataSet dataSet,
    int startRecord,
    int maxRecords,
    string srcTable
)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxs7kbfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

However, I don't know what should be passed to srcTable. My stored proc has one REF_CURSOR
(OUT TYPES.REF_CURSOR).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `srcTable` parameter is the name of the `DataTable` in `DataSet` object.

**EDIT:**

The `DataSet` object automatically adds a table when you call `Fill` if you have not explicitly created one.  The Default name is "Table".  I do not believe the `DataSet` object *cares* about what type of data it is being filled with.  It still creates the `DataTable`.

Before you call `Fill()` on your `DataAdapter`.  Add an empty table to the `DataSet` with a name so you are able to access it during the `Fill()` method:

```
ds.Tables.Add("myTableName");
```

Then call the proper overloaded `Fill()` method like so:

```
da.Fill(ds, 1, 1000, "myTableName");
```

Or if you just use the default name of the table, or are unsure of the name of the table you created (doubtful):

```
da.Fill(ds, 1, 1000, ds.Tables[0].TableName);
```

Spcifically using your example it should look like this:

```
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add();
da.Fill(ds, 1, maxRowCount, ds.Tables[0].TableName);//Here is where I need to limit the rows
```

Comment: As you can see from the code snippet, there is no tables added in the dataset. The output is a cursor.

Comment: Populating a `DataSet` with any data automatcially creates and adds a `DataTable`.  Step past your `Fill` then look at the `Tables` property on the set in you debugger.  Because you didn't delcare a table explicitly, you can use the `ds.Tables[0].TableName` example.

Comment: Why should not the code throw? You just created a dataset and at that time there is no tables, still you are trying to pass the index 0 to a function?

Comment: Like I said, 0 is the index of the table that the *DataSet automatically creates when you call fill*.  Test it and see.

Comment: No you didn't. After fill, the dataset is populated, I got that. But in the example you are providing an empty dataset and so you are providing a null reference to the fill function. It wont work.

Comment: I see what you are saying, sorry.  Why can't you just add a table to the DataSet before you fill it since it is *just going to add one anyway*.  I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: That brings us to the original question. When a cursor is the output parameter, what is the name of the Table in the dataset? I debugged and found it is "Table". So in case of a single cursor it has to be da.Fill(ds, 1, 1000, "Table"); You mentioned this in your answer, but as an example of Table name. If you edit the answer to reflect our findings, I can mark this as answer.